How to generate an access token using a refresh token in FastAPI?
I am working on a FastAPI project where I have a requirement to automatically generate a new access token using a refresh token when the access token expires. If you have any documentation or GitHub links related to this, please provide them.
I tried multiple methods but none of them worked.
def get_access_from_refresh_token(refresh_token: str):
    print('in get access token', refresh_token)
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(refresh_token, JWT_SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
    except(JWTError) as e:
      print(e,"******************JWTError*******************")

    print(payload,"******************payload****************")


Answer 1
Docs FastAPI JWT Auth
